# how to trigger notification from other framework in atmosphere (comet)?

Tags: java, comet, atmosphere

basically i have read some samples, but all are self contained in one servlet.
such as: use doGet to establish the long polling connection, and then use doPost to trigger the event to notify all suspended connections.

Here is my question: I have other web actions programming in spring mvc, in the spring mvc controller a user post a message via /message/post, how can I make this action to trigger the atmosphere handler to notify the suspended connections?

Answer (score 2):

> But what about non web components (EJB, JMS, Akka/Scala Actor, etc.) or web component with different scope (another web application, another Servlet, etc.)? They can also generate server sides events by using Atmosphere’s BroadcasterFactory

http://jfarcand.wordpress.com/2010/06/18/trick-of-the-friday-1-delivering-server-side-events-to-your-websocketcomet-application/

Comment: Yes, this should work, just remember to do your lookup for an AkkaBroadcaster: http://github.com/jboner/akka/blob/master/akka-http/src/main/scala/AkkaBroadcaster.scala