# Configurable Comet servlet with Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc, comet

I added Comet servlet into Spring web application. This servlet does not differ from the example of a servlet: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/aio.html#Example_code

I can connected in javascript to this comet servlet but when there need to transfer data (READ Event) then it's only going to timeout so the function writer.flush(); in MessageSender isn't work

I think this servlet is Spring blocked.
There are other opinions and how can I added comet servlet in Spring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See related [qestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456357/how-do-i-use-comet-with-spring-mvc).

It is good aproach - to use [Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere) library.